# foreach пропустить и добавить одну запись

Tags: php, foreach

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно пропустить одну запись (если совпадает id) и вместо нее добавить следующую запись.

Есть блок с выводом последних 5 новостей, при просмотре одной новости. В этом блоке выводятся все последние новости с указанным лимитом в 5 новостей.

Если отрываю любую из последних 5 новостей, соответственно в блоке "последние новости" есть и эта открытая новость (что не совсем логично, показывать ее, на этой же странице).

Можно ли как-то если ID текущей открытой новости совпадает с ID в блоке последних новостей, пропустить ее и добавить к списку еще одну запись чтобы по прежнему в блоке оставалось 5 новостей?

Сейчас работает так:

```
foreach($mod->related as $related){ 
    if ($related->id == $id) {
        continue;
    } 
//related
}
```

1) в настройках указан лимит - 5 новостей

2) $related->id - это id последних новостей в блоке

3) $id - это ID текущей открытой новости

В данном случае, новость в блоке новостей не дублируется (пропускает). Но в итоге отображается не 5 новостей а 4 новости (т.к. одну пропускает из-за совпадения ID). Соответственно если открыть 6 новость, там будет отображаться их 5шт, т.к. ID не будет совпадать.

Как вариант можно указать лимит в 6 новостей, но тогда при открытии новостей после 6 записи в блоке будет их уже 7шт.

Как можно реализовать чтобы всегда было 5 новостей, но при этом не дублировалась новость в блоке.

Спасибо.

Comment: Как у вас делается выборка новостей из БД? Обычно в таких случаях в запросе выборки исключают текущий ID.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Благодаря Вам все получилось. Одной строчкой в модели  — **$this->db->where_not_in('news_id', $id);**

Answer (score 0):

Сделай цикл for и лимит в 6 записей.
Или ограничьте на уровне БД.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mod->related) && $i < 5; $i++) {
    $related = $mod->related[$i];
    if($related->id == $id)
        continue;
    // related    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Учту на будущее. Вопрос уже решен (в комментарии выше добавлено решение)